# Sampling data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two pieces of data. One is the actual `fulldata` which is a dataset of 49625x6 numeric data, and the other is the index of that data with the target_class named `Book2` which is 49625x1.

Book2 has six names (strings) repeated over and over again to match the fulldata dataset entries. I want to take 1,000 samples from fulldata of which 25% of the 1000 samples are "blue" and 75% are "red" using Book2, then contain this in a new subsample named `sampledata`.

How can I achieve this in MATLAB?

Pseudo Code:

Choose 250 blue samples from Book2, not sure how to "choose" 250 random "blue" samples
`bluesample = indX(Book2, :)` or `Book2(indX, :)` not sure.

Choose 750 Red samples from Book2, again not sure how to "choose" 750 random "red" samples
`redsample = indX(Book2, ;)` or `Book2(indX, :)` again not sure here.

Combine blue and red samples into subsample.

```
subsample = join(bluesample, redsample)
```

Find the indices of subsample and create sampledata from fulldata:

```
sampledata = subsample(indX(fulldata), :) This line is probably wrong
```

This is an image of the two datasets:

[image]

Each row in Book2 matches the row in fulldata. I am trying to achieve the ability to choose a certain amount of "normal" and a certain amount of "not normal" (yes, I know they are not aptly named) data from fulldata using Book2, as Book2 is the indices of fulldata and contains the class labels.

So in terms of my dataset it might be said easier this way:

```
Choose 250 random samples of the string "normal." from Book2 and log the row number.
Choose 750 random samples of the string "not normal." from Book2 and log the row number.
Combine the two random samples of row numbers together.
Make a new dataset (1000x6) using the combined row numbers (above) of fulldata.
```

Comment: I havent tried anything Ben :( I dont use matlab much so just need a helping hand on this. Normally I would try but I dont know how to use loops etc

Comment: *but I dont know how to use loops etc* look up a matlab tutorial, also the question is a bit vague, are red and blue strings in these tables, maybe give some examples of what the tables look like and show what you want to do

Comment: @Ben not sure if that has cleared anything up for you. Also I did mention that Book2 has 6 "names" so yes they are strings.

Comment: Yeah, that is a great change to the question, it is much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the 'normal' records using strmatch:

```
normIdx = strmatch('normal.', Book2);
normalSubset = fulldata(normIdx, :);
```

Then to generate a list of 250 random non repeating integers I googled "matlab list of non repeated random integers" and from [the first result](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/283155):

```
p = randperm(size(normalSubset , 1));
p = p(1:250)-1;
```

So now to get your 250 randomly selected normal records

```
normalSample = normalSubset (p, :);
```

`normalSample` will be 250 x 6. now do the same with 'not normal.' to get a `notNormalSample` (750 x 6) and then combine then to get

```
sample = [normalSample ; notNormalSample ]
```

So in `sample` all the normals will appear before the not normals, if you want to mix them up use `randperm()` again:

```
sample = sample(randperm(1000), :);
```

Comment: Hi Dan there is a bit of an error with the last line, this will only choose 1000x1 not 1000x6. Still accepted your answer tho, you might want to correct it tho for some else looking at the question.