# randperm of multiple columns

Tags: matlab

on a previous question here [Sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355372/sampling-data-in-matlab) the answer given for sample on the last line of code only returns 1000x1 rather than 1000x6?

```
%% 
normIdx = strmatch('normal.', Book2);
normalSubset = fulldata(normIdx, :);
normal = randperm(size(normalSubset , 1));
p = normal(1:750)-1;

%
smurfIdx = strmatch('smurf.', Book2);
smurfSubset = fulldata(smurfIdx, :);
smurf = randperm(size(smurfSubset , 1));
a = smurf(1:250)-1;

%
normalSample = normalSubset (p, :);
smurfSample = smurfSubset (a, :);

%
sample = [normalSample ; smurfSubset]

%
sample = sample(randperm(1000)); % this line
```

I tried:

```
sample = randperm( size(sample, 1));
```

This outputs 28 thousand records on one line, obviously not what I want. I then tried:

```
rows = 1000;
columns = 6;

%# pick random columns
 indY = randperm( size(sample,2) );
 indY = indY(1:columns);

%# pick random rows
indX = randperm( size(sample,1) );
indX = indX(1:rows)';

%# filter data
sample = [indX ; indY];
```

But I couldnt concatenate the last line? This was only an attempt to try fix the 1000x6 problem, if anyone could come up with a better way "a working way".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
 sample = sample(randperm(1000),:);
```