# randperm or shuffle two datasets at the same time

Tags: matlab, random, permutation

I have a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412283/matching-row-samples-to-class-labels) and I think im running into a problem because I cant shuffle the sample data and the indices of sample data (idx) at the same time.

I have a dataset called `fulldata` of which contains 49 thousand rows by 6 columns, I then have another dataset which is the class labels for fulldata (Book2) which contains numerous class labels which correspond to the exact rows in fulldata.

I wanted to only pick two class labels from fulldata (normal. and smurf.) of which I wanted 750 normal rows and 250 smurf rows.

I then wanted to shuffle randomly the new sample data (1000x6).

Up to this point was managed. But then I get stuck... Dan helped on the previous question but then I noticed that k1 outputs some of the other class labels from Book2 such as neptune etc and that shouldnt be the case... K1 should only contain smurf and normal class labels.

The reason why I ask this is because I want to use the baysian classifier in matlab and in order to use it I need:

```
Test_Data (unseen data)
Trainning_data (This is the sample data im trying to create above)
Target_class (this is the class labels that match exactly each row in sample data)
```

Comment: Could you rephrase it a bit to make it more clear what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: shuffle two datasets at the same time? I cant think of another way to rephrase it.

Comment: Maybe you show something that looks like your input, and show your desired output data. (On small scale or with just a few lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
idx = [smurfIdx(a);normIdx(p)];
```

And then make sure you use @Dan's recommendation from the previous question, i.e.

```
shuffle = randperm(1000);
sample = sample(shuffle,:);
K1 = Book2(idx (shuffle), :);
```

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the question is somewhat vague, so it is not clear where you are stuck exactly. However, I've taken the liberty to review your previous questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355372/sampling-data-in-matlab) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412283/matching-row-samples-to-class-labels)), so here's is my attempt at solving your problem:

For the purpose of this answer, lets generate a random data set first, similar to yours:

```
classes = {'normal.', 'smurf.', 'neptune.', 'eject.', 'portsweep.'};
fulldata = ceil(1e3 * rand(49000, 6));
Book2 = {classes{ceil(numel(classes) * rand(size(fulldata, 1), 1))}}';
```

Lets randomly choose 750 rows corresponding to "normal" tags and 250 rows corresponding to "smurf" tags. However, instead of applying `randperm` on the data itself and choosing the first N values (like you did in your previous questions), you should rather create a vector of random indices and use it to index into both `fulldata` and `Book2` arrays, like so:

```
idxnormal = strmatch('normal.', Book2);            % # Find normals
idxnormal = idxnormal(randperm(numel(idxnormal))); % # Random shuffle of normals
idxsmurf = strmatch('smurf.', Book2);              % # Find smurfs
idxsmurf = idxsmurf(randperm(numel(idxsmurf)));    % # Random shuffle of smurfs
idx = [idxnormal(1:750); idxsmurf(1:250)];         % # 750 normals and 250 smurfs
idx = idx(randperm(numel(idx)));                   % # Random shuffle
```

`idx` now holds random indices into `fulldata`/'Book2', which correspond only to "normal" or "smurf" tags. Now lets retrieve a subset of the data with the corresponding tags:

```
subsetdata = fulldata(idx, :);
K1 = Book2(idx);
```

Comment: I may have found a problem using the above, [see new question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426665/sample-data-causing-problems-with-naive-bayes-classifier) not sure if its the sampling or the classifier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after reading the previous questions I hope to have understood the question. In case I am right you just have forgotten to filter your data first and extract only smurf and normal.

In this case you should look into logical indexing: http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html;jsessionid=97fa707e5059807b7ecae8969810

Use this to extract the right subset before drawing your datapoints and you should be OK.